# Displaying alphanumerical values in a textbox(Not based on database value)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to display Order number which is alphanumeric value to be displayed in a textbox.Whenever the page get reloaded,the value should be automatically incremented..eg:A0001,A0002,A0003,....like this..
Pls anyone help me..

Comment: Give us your code

Comment: I don't know how to do this..I'm new to php

Comment: Give us the image at least with example. Your explanation is unclear

Comment: Consider a billing system...I will enter an OrderNo with 'A0001' and it gets populated in the database.

Comment: When i reload the form again,The order no textbox should be incremented to 'A0002' automatically

Comment: Why would you want to increment the order number based on page reloads? Shouldn't it only increment if the previous order was actually *submitted*?

Comment: Yes..Pls provide me the code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["uid"]))
{
$_SESSION["uid"]=0;
}
$prefix='A000';
$id=$_SESSION["uid"]+1;
$_SESSION["uid"]=$id;
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $prefix.$id; ?>">
```